# What can be said about $A$ if $P(A) = \{ \emptyset, \{x\}, \{y\},\{x,y\}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

What can be said about $A$ if $P(A) = \{ \emptyset, \{x\}, \{y\},\{x,y\}\}$

I'm not entirely sure what this question is asking, but here is what I would assume my answer should be:

$A=\{x, y\}$

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Yes: that is exactly what you can say about $A$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks so much!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Leave that as an answer so this question can be answered.

Comment: Note that $\bigcup\mathcal P(X)=X$, for any set $X$.

Comment: @bof can you please elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: @bof this subject of study is new to me and I'm still learning and understanding how to interpret what questions are asking of me.  Sorry if what is obvious to you is not so obvious to me!  I'm still learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the power set of $A$ you get every subset. Note that there are 4 elements in $P(A)$, this implies that $A$ has two elements, since $2^2 = 4$. The only subset of $P(A)$ is $\{x,y\}$ which must be $A$.

In fact, if $A$ is finite, the largest element in $P(A)$ (if we look at the cardinality of that element) is $A$ itself

Comment: I thought I understood your answer until I read my next question which has 3 elements.  What can be said about $A$ if $P(A)=\{\emptyset, \{a\},\{\{a\}\}\}$.  There are 3 elements, so how many would this imply that $A$ has?

Comment: @inquisitor $P(A)$ cannot have exactly $3$ elements, so $P(A)=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{\{a\}\}\}$ is possible only if $a=\{a\}$, and then $A=a$. If your set theory has an axiom which forbids $a=\{a\}$, then $P(A)=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{\{a\}\}\}$ is impossible.

Comment: @bof ahhh.. maybe that is the point of the question!

Comment: Note that $# P(A) = 2^n$ for a given $n$. This holds for every $A$.